# Git cant init submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have trouble initing submodules, I created with "git submodule add".

I tried:

```
git clone --recursive
```

or

```
git clone —recurse-submodules -j8
```

or

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

or

```
git submodule status
```

or

```
git submodule deinit --all
git submodule init
```

Everytime the output is empty

my .gitmodules(created with git submodule add ...):

```
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/gorilla/mux"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/gorilla/mux
    url = https://github.com/gorilla/mux
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware
    url = https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
    url = https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/urfave/negroni"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/urfave/negroni
    url = https://github.com/urfave/negroni
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/gorilla/handlers"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/gorilla/handlers
    url = https://github.com/gorilla/handlers
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/sirupsen/logrus
    url = https://github.com/Sirupsen/logrus
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/couchbase/gocb"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/couchbase/gocb
    url = https://github.com/couchbase/gocb
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/google/uuid"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/google/uuid
    url = https://github.com/google/uuid
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go
    url = https://github.com/opentracing/opentracing-go
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/golang/snappy"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/golang/snappy
    url = https://github.com/golang/snappy
[submodule "vendor/src/golang.org/x/net"]
    path = vendor/src/golang.org/x/net
    url = https://github.com/golang/net
[submodule "vendor/src/golang.org/x/text"]
    path = vendor/src/golang.org/x/text
    url = https://github.com/golang/text
[submodule "vendor/src/github.com/satori/go.uuid"]
    path = vendor/src/github.com/satori/go.uuid
    url = https://github.com/satori/go.uuid
```

I'm using Git version 2.19.2.windows.1

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you add a submodule, you should see the corresponding subfolder being created/populated with the content of the remote repository you are referencing.

So vendor/src/github.com/gorilla/mux should be filled out with https://github.com/auth0/go-jwt-middleware

Once that is done, since there are no other modification, commands like `git submodule update/init/status` will return nothing: the init/update is already done, and the status has nothing to report.

But try first the [go 1.11 modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules): [`go mod vendor`](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-do-i-use-vendoring-with-modules-is-vendoring-going-away) would be doing the vendoring for you, and avoid git submodules, which you might not need for a regular go project.
From there: `go build -mod=vendor` would be enough to build your project.

Comment: After cloning repo i have no vendor folder. How can i fetch all my deps ?

Comment: By following the go modules article: it will fetch the dependencies for you , and put them in the vendor folder, that you can then add, commit and push.